# Why is it not possible to tweet the following phrase?

Tags: twitter

Why can I not tweet

```
M as in Mancy
```

I've tried on mobile and desktop, is there something wrong with that specific phrase?  I know you can include that phrase in other tweets and it will work, but that phrase by itself (without spaces or other alterations) is untweetable.

Comment: 'M<space>' must correspond to a command. Like 'd<space>@<user>' triggers a direct message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Twitter,

**M [username] + message**

or

**D [username] + message**

sends that person a Direct Message that goes to their device, and saves in their web archive.

Examples:

**d krissy want to pick a Jamba Juice for me while you're there?**

or

**m krissy wanna pick up a Jamba Juice for me while you're there?**

performs the same action. So that's why your phrase can't be tweeted.